# Interpreting Results

Tags: r, regression, linear

I have included the results that I got from a homework problem, but am a bit confused on how to interpret them.  The dataset contains information from schools about vaccination rates and exemptions along with enrollment and school type. Enrollment I can interpret just fine but what I'm having trouble with is the `pubprivPUBLIC` coefficient. It is binomial, where public is 1 and private is 0. Even though the p-values are above 0.05, I still need to be able to interpret this type of coefficient.

How do I interpret the `pubprivPUBLIC` coefficient?

[image]

Comment: @Poi56170 here's a search to get you started https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=interpret%20regression%20categorical%20answers%3a1%20-logistic%20-logit%20score%3a3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient on such an indicator variable indicates the difference in mean outcome between 0 and 1 values when other predictors are held constant. Outcomes are on average 0.184 lower when public rather than private or 0.184 higher other way round.

(I would say here indicator or binary rather than binomial, but there are many competing terms for (0, 1) variables. Economists in particular seem compelled to use the ugly term "dummy variable", all too often misunderstood within social science as disparaging.)

Comment: Thank you so much!